# MySQL Query to get prescriptions statistics at end of year for store people

Tags: php, mysql, join

I needs a query, that brings me result in following manner:

```
prescription created date
right lens product
left lens product
store name
is prescription used for order **Yes / no**
```

My database tables are as following:

```
**prescriptions**
  creation_date
  right_product_id
  left_product_id
  store_id
  customer_id

**products**
  id
  name1

**stores**
  id
  name

**orders** 
  id
  store_id
  customer_id

**order_products**
  id
  order_id
  right_product_id
  left_product_id
```

One problem is that, I have not used `prescription_id` with my orders table, so I cannot bring a direct result hence I need to use `customer_id` and `store_id` fields to match for prescription and order placed or not.

Can anyone, please make me a query that brings above result?

**Result should be something like this:**

prescription_date | right_lens_product | left_lens_product | Store | Prescription Used

2012/12/12 | product 1 | product 2 | xYZ Store | Yes/No

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add data for the tables and then mention that in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT p.creation_date, pr1.name1, pr2.name1, s.name, if(p.creation_date IS NULL, 'Yes', 'No')
FROM (order_products op, stores s, products p1, products p2, orders o)
LEFT JOIN prescriptions p ON p.customer_id = o.customer_id AND p.store_id = o.store_id
WHERE o.id = op.order_id AND s.id = o.store_id AND p1.id = op.right_product_id AND p2.id = left_product_id
```

This is just a close guess without having the tables actually setup, but should be close (as I understand the question).

Left joining the prescription table allows us to tell if the order was related to a prescription or not.

Comment: here is updated query as per corrections required: `SELECT p.created_on, p1.product_title1, p2.product_title1, s.name1, if(p.created_on IS NULL, 'Yes', 'No')
FROM (order_products op, stores s, productlens p1, productlens p2, orders o)
LEFT JOIN prescriptions p ON p.cusomter_id = o.customer_id AND p.store_id = o.store_id
WHERE o.id = op.order_id AND s.id = o.store_id AND p1.id = op.right_product_id AND p2.id = op.left_product_id` it gives error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'p.cusomter_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: You are receiving the error as the column 'p.cusomter_id' is misspelt. It should be p.customer_id.